# asp.net MVC3 razor webgrid EditColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I have a *Webgrid* which is bounded and also has an edit "LinkButton" column.

I want it so that when the user clicks "LinkButton", it will fill a TextBox (below the WebGrid) with some value from the database.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Do you need to do a round-trip to the controller to get the value from the database?  Or do you mean the value is already present in the model?

Comment: i need to do a round-trip to the controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for this, on click of the link button call a jquery.

From the jquery call an action and make that action do whatever work you want and return THAT value to the jquery and then use this value to fill the textbox.

Here is a link, that shows how to call an action from jquery

http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-an-action-from-javascript-or-jquery-in-mvc-3-razor/